# Progress uploading files with formidable

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I'm using node.js-expresss backend with formidable package. I tried to implement a progress bar and decided to used formidable & websockets:

```
const create = (req, res, io) => {
  logger.debug(`EXEC create material`)
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.encoding = 'utf-8'
  form.keepExtensions = true
  form.multiples = true
  form.maxFileSize = 600 * 1024 * 1024 // 600MB instead of 200MB (default value)
  // form.uploadDir = `${__dirname}/uploads`
  let oldValue = 0
  form.on('progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) => {
    let currentValue = (parseFloat(bytesReceived) / parseFloat(bytesExpected)) * 100
    if ((currentValue - oldValue) > 1 || currentValue === 100) {
      oldValue = currentValue
      io.emit('FILE_UPLOAD_STATUS', currentValue)
      console.log('FILE_UPLOAD_STATUS', currentValue)
    }
  })
...
```

However it seeems to process files and show progress once all files are uploaded? Files can be quite big so I see a progress bar empty in the browser, till the end when it goes from 0% to 100% in a really short period of time.

Should I change my code and get the progress from the xhr request?

Comment: frontend code please. nothing is received in that channel? Going by official documentation it should send an update after every successful chunk is processed.

Comment: other answers have mentioned this, `((bytesRecieved * 100)/bytesExpected)`.

Comment: channel receives data, but after a while doing nothing. It seems when form.on.progress get fired all files are already uploaded but not processed by formidable. So progress get fired but it run so fast in comparison to file uploading

Comment: form.on is an event facilitated by Formidable itself right? How is that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to move it to js inside browser successfully. Using axios as it's the easiest/fastest way to deal with progress. This is my code in case of interest (React app):

````
axios.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${PRIVATE_API_ROOT}/materials`,
      data: formData,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
        this.setState({
          progressStatus: parseFloat(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total * 100).toFixed(2),
        })
      }
    }).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        progressStatus: 100,
        loading: false,
        error: ''
      })
    }).catch(function (error) {
      //handle error
      this.setState({ error: error.message })
    });
```
````